# Group and sort a vector by common/repetitive elements in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

Suppose I have a vector as follows

```
std::vector<int> v = {3, 9, 7, 7, 2};
```

I would like to sort this vector of elements so that the vector will be stored as 77932. So first, we store the common elements (7), then we sort the remaining elements from the highest to the lowest.

If I have a vector as follows

```
std::vector<int> v = {3, 7, 7, 7, 2};
```

Here, it would lead to 77732.

Same for

```
std::vector<int> v = {7, 9, 2, 7, 9};
```

it should lead to 99772, because the 9s are higher than 7s.

One last example

```
std::vector<int> v = {7, 9, 7, 7, 9};
```

it should lead to 77799, because there are more 7s than 9s.

What could be the fastest algorithm to implement this?

Comment: Create a "count" map, then order with comparer `[&count_map](int lhs, int rhs) {std::tie(count_map(lhs), lhs) < std::tie(count_map(rhs), rhs);}`.

Comment: Maybe you should count the number of occurence of each element to build something like an histogram, then sort your histogram by the number of occurrence and value then reconstruct your vector. That is the simplest way you could do it, maybe there is some other optimized way of doing it...

Comment: Is it 11122960 or 22111960, i.e. does the count of multiple elements matter? Also, are values of the numbers limited, e.g. to be in [0,128] or similar?

Comment: Btw, what have you tried so far?

Comment: It is 11122960. Yes values should be limitied in [0,12].I have not yet tried any solutions right now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `std::multiset` to do counting for you. Then sort using a simple custom comparer with tie breaking logic implemented with `std::tie`:

```
std::vector<int> data = {7, 9, 2, 7, 9};
std::multiset<int> count(data.begin(), data.end());
std::sort(
    data.begin()
,   data.end()
,   [&](int a, int b) {
        int ca = count.count(a);
        int cb = count.count(b);
        return std::tie(ca, a) > std::tie(cb, b);
    }
);
std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

[Demo 1](https://ideone.com/HYdBZj)

**Edit:** `count(n)` function of of `std::multiset` is linear in the number of duplicates, which may degrade the performance of your sorting algorithm. You can address this by using `std::unordered_map` in its place:

```
std::vector<int> data = {7, 9, 2, 7, 9};
std::unordered_map<int,int> count;
for (auto v : data)
    count[v]++;
std::sort(
    data.begin()
,   data.end()
,   [&](int a, int b) {
        return std::tie(count[a], a) > std::tie(count[b], b);
    }
);
std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

[Demo 2.](https://ideone.com/EUYh7M)

Comment: I guess this runs on O(n log n)

Comment: @csl This could be O(n (log n) (log n)), with the extra (log n) coming from `count.count` calls inside O(n log n) sorting algorithm.

Comment: `count.count` is a O(k log n) term, where k is the duplicate count. The worst case is then O(n^2 log^2 n)

Comment: @Caleth You are right, I edited to make this an O(n log n) with `unordered_map`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need an auxiliary frequency count structure, then you can just define a comparator lambda and use whatever sort you like, `std::sort` is a sensible default

```
std::unordered_map<int, size_t> frequency;
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end()
            , [&](int i) { ++frequency[i]; });
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end()
        , [&](int lhs, int rhs)
          { 
            return std::tie(frequency[lhs], lhs) < std::tie(frequency[rhs], rhs);
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be satisfied if a candidate proposed an auxiliary map for this task - clearly a sort does most of the work, and the auxiliary structure should be a vector (or, after I've actually tried to implement it, 2 vectors):

```
void custom_sort(vector<int> &v)
{
if (v.size() < 2)
    return;

sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<int>());

vector<int> dupl;
vector<int> singl;
int d;
bool dv = false;
for (int i = 1; i < v.size(); ++i)
{
    if (!dv)
    {
        if (v[i - 1] == v[i])
        {
            d = v[i];
            dv = true;
            dupl.push_back(d);
        }
        else
        {
            singl.push_back(v[i - 1]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dupl.push_back(d);
        if (v[i] != d)
            dv = false;
    }
}

if (!dv)
    singl.push_back(v.back());
else
    dupl.push_back(d);

auto mid = copy(dupl.begin(), dupl.end(), v.begin());
copy(singl.begin(), singl.end(), mid);
}
```

But yes, the branching is tricky - if you want to use it for more than an inverview, please test it... :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it does not seem to match the last example that I give above: std::vector<int> v = {7, 9, 7, 7, 9}; It should give 77799, but it gives 99777...

Comment: Yes, you're right - either I've overlooked the example, or it wasn't there when I read the question. I suppose the algorithm above could be generalized for more than 2 alternatives, but frankly it's already complicated enough - I'd probably go with dasblinkenlight's solution...

Comment: It's not your fault, I added the last part of the question later.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** this answers an early version of the question.

If the elements are small integers, i.e. have limited range, we can extend the [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) algorithm (since the keys here are the elements, we don't need to establish the starting position separately).

```
void custom_sort(std::vector<int>&v, const int N)
// assume that all elements are in [0,N[ and N elements fit into cash
{
  vector<int> count(N);
  for(auto x:v)
    count.at(x) ++;   // replace by count[x]++ if you're sure that 0 <= x < N
  int i=0;
  // first pass: insert multiple elements
  for(auto n=N-1; n>=0; --n)
    if(count[n] > 1)
      for(auto k=0; k!=count[n]; ++k)
        v[i++] = n;
  // second pass: insert single elements
  for(auto n=N-1; n>=0; --n)
    if(count[n] == 1)
      v[i++] = n;
}
```

Comment: The trick is that in my above example, I gave a vector of int, but my application needs actually a vector of a particular class (which can compared  to each other like >, <, or ==). So I am not sure it is the right way to do it for my application.

Answer (score 0):

There is O(N Log(N))  algorithm with extra O(N)  memory.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

int main(){

    typedef std::pair<int, int> pii;
    typedef std::vector< int > vi ;
    typedef std::vector< pii > vii;

    vi v = {7, 9, 7, 7, 9};

    //O( N log(N) )
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());


    vii vc;
    vc.reserve(v.size());

    // O (N)  make (cnt, value) pair of vector
    for(size_t i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (vc.empty() ||  v[i] != vc.back().second ){
           vc.push_back( pii(0, v[i]) ) ;
        }

        vc.back().first ++ ;
    }

    // O (N Log(N) )  sort by (cnt, value)
    std::sort( vc.begin(), vc.end() ) ;

    // O(N)   restore they, reverse order.
    v.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)vc.size(); ++i){
        int rev_i = vc.size() - i - 1;
        int cnt =  vc[rev_i].first;
        for(int k = 0; k < cnt; ++k)
          v.push_back( vc[rev_i].second ) ;
    }

    /////////////////////////

    for(size_t i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i){
        printf("%4d, ", v[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```